# Build Docker image of a Python Flask app shows a blank REST endpoint route

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask

I am using docker to build a flask restful project, but when I ran docker, the **URL** exposed shows a blank page.

I am a newbie with docker, I need some guidance.

I am suspecting the Dockerfile not pointing well on the `app.py` which finally runs the project. Below is my project structure :

```
project/
     app/
        movie/
          movies.py
     utils/
        tasks.py
     app.py
     requirements.txt
```

This is how my `app.py` file looks like :

```
from app import app


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Hello World'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Then, this is my `Dockefile`  :

```
FROM alpine:latest

MAINTAINER huxyy

RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

#ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
#
#CMD ["app.py"]

# Run app.py when the container launches
COPY app.py /app
CMD python3 app.py
```

So I first ran the build command :

`docker build -t flaskapp:latest .`

Then after I ran the image :

```
docker run -it flaskapp
```

So, I don't know whats wrong , but I kindly need some guidance

Comment: you have not published any port. Try `docker run -it -p 5000:5000 flaskapp` and access it on `localhost:5000`

Comment: That  too doesn't work @michalk

Comment: Also bind to `0.0.0.0` - `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)`

Comment: Ok , am updating @michalk

Comment: Am now getting `docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint awesome_chandrasekhar (ef7a5eec3becd6eacb40a7ff5e017423987afe150275dffeb214e4b2af4c4703): Bind for 0.0.0.0:5000 fa
iled: port is already allocated. After rebuilding docker
` @michalk

Comment: Have resolved the top error, though , the link is not working, aren't I missing something in the `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: First stop the container using that port or check if there is another service using it

Comment: @IdrisStack use can use `docker logs` to see the log of the docker container to see what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks @RicardoSanchez, I resolved it, but my initial issue is still persisting

Comment: @JarvisLuong, I ran it and showed that it's running       

`Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 602-136-444`

Comment: Of which when I navigate to `http://0.0.0.0:5000/ `, it's blank

Comment: Maybe try opening the browser network tab, see what http status does the server returns? 404 or what? @IdrisStack

Comment: Its `200` in the network tab, but it shows this **This site can’t be reached**

Comment: btw, this image would give better performance. https://github.com/tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask-docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that the port 5000 that you try to access the app on is not actually published despite using `EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile.

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
>   the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
>   more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
>   to high-order ports.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Try running the container with the `-p` flag to publish your desired port mapping like:

```
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 flaskapp
```

Comment: Tried this one , but still no luck, have a look on my [repo](https://github.com/huxaiphaer/starwars_challenge)

Comment: I have just pulled your code, built the image and run the container with `docker run -it -p 5000:5000 flaskapp` and it works.

Comment: ```$ curl -iv http://localhost:5000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 61
Content-Length: 61
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Server: Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.7.4
Server: Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.7.4
< Date: Sun, 19 Jan 2020 10:43:41 GMT```

Comment: What could be missing on my side ?

Comment: what response are you seeing after running the container with the `-p` flag?

Comment: Does also the browser show `Hello World` ? , because , when I check in the networt tab, it shows `200` but doesn't show anything in the browser.

Comment: After running the command with `-p`, the server starts , but when I click on `http://0.0.0.0:5000/ `, it shows nothing in the web browser, yet when I run the application without docker , it shows `Hello World`

Comment: Yes it shows `Welcome to Star Wars End point. Test the endpoints in postman`. 
Btw have you tried reaching `http://localhost:5000` using curl?

Comment: Aaah I see what the issue is. Use `http://localhost:5000` not `http://0.0.0.0:5000/`

Comment: Oooh , I get it , it's running, maybe you can differentiate for me why we indicacted `0.0.0.0`  in binding

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown, or non-applicable target (a ‘no particular address’ place holder) while `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address (also known as `localhost`).

Comment: No worries. Cheers!